# Parenscript and implicit Return

Tags: javascript, lisp, common-lisp, parenscript

Is there anyway to turn off Parenscript's implicit Return?

I'm trying to write the following code:

```
function () = { dialog.show();};
```

But Parenscript inserts an implicit return:

```
(ps (lambda ()
      (chain dialog (show))))
```

=>

```
function () = { return dialog.show();};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `(values)`:

```
(ps (lambda ()
      (chain dialog (show))
      (values)))
```

This should probably return `undefined` (but it actually returns `null`).  If you really need `undefined`, you have it:

```
(ps (lambda ()
      (chain dialog (show))
      undefined))
```

Answer (score 3):

No. (CoffeeScript works the same way, too.) This is a feature, not a bug. Explicitly return `undefined` if you really care.